TV show or movie, possibly from the 1970s, descendents of some people who perjured themselves
Possibly from '70's. Maybe from anthology on TV or TV movie. Film/episode about a group of people who call themselves "Pergies" or Perjies. Not sure of spelling. Character/s from a long time ago (in the plot) PERJURED himself or themselves. Descendants were then known as "Pergies". Please help. Have looked EVERYWHERE. Cannot remember any of the credits.

Hi, welcome to SF&F.  Did these people have any special powers, or where they somehow non-human?

What sort of time period/world was the story set in?

Hi. It was modern times. So the mid to late 70's. I don't remember them having powers. I think they may have been fallen angels. But I was prob 6 or 7 when I saw it. Could've sworn Matt Clark was in it. The other characters were a man and a woman I think. Human. Possibly film makers. Maybe took a wrong turn. I know it's very vague but I finally realized it wasn't The People ... I'd been mixing the plots as a kid. Hope that helps. This was the only way I could answer you guys. Can you tell me if there's a different way to just answer YOUR questions re: clarification? Thanks!
